# DSL query to find the elements from array of dictionaries

Tags: elasticsearch, dsl

I have a index in elastic search called `professor`

- If for cross field i need "AND" condition
- for same field array i need to OR condition

1. I need to search `BusinessArea` which is `Research` or `Accounting` this is array of fields(OR) statement

   AND
2. I need to search `Role` is `Developer` or `Tester` condition this is array of fields(OR) statement

   AND
3. I need to search `Location` is `NY`(&) condition

```
test = [{ 'id': '1', 'name': 'Group1', 'BusinessArea': [ { 'id': '14', 'name': 'Accounting' }, { 'id': '3', 'name': 'Accounting' } ],'Designation': [ { 'id': '16', 'name': 'L1' }, { 'id': '20', 'name': 'L2' }, { 'id': '25', 'name': 'L2' }, ] }, { 'id': '2', 'name': 'Group1', 'BusinessArea': [ { 'id': '14', 'name': 'Research' }, { 'id': '3', 'name': 'Accounting' } ], 'Role': [ { 'id': '5032', 'name': 'Tester' }, { 'id': '5033', 'name': 'Developer' } ], 'Designation': [ { 'id': '16', 'name': 'L1' }, { 'id': '20', 'name': 'L2' }, { 'id': '25', 'name': 'L2' }, ] }, { 'id': '1', 'name': 'Group1', 'BusinessArea': [ { 'id': '14', 'name': 'Research' }, { 'id': '3', 'name': 'Engineering' } ], 'Role': [ { 'id': '5032', 'name': 'Developer' }, { 'id': '5033', 'name': 'Developer' } ], 'Designation': [ { 'id': '16', 'name': 'L1' }, { 'id': '20', 'name': 'L2' }, { 'id': '25', 'name': 'L2' }] }]
```

Query is below,3rd one got it, How to add `1 and 2`

```
content_search = es.search(index="professor", body={
    "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "match_all": {}
      },
      "filter": [
        {
          "term": {
            "Location.keyword": "NY"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
})
content_search ['hits']['hits']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need to search Location is NY(&) condition

I have not added this condition, since there is no field named `Location` in your sample data

Try out this below query:

**Search Query:**

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "terms": {
            "BusinessArea.name.keyword": [
              "Research",
              "Accounting"
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "terms": {
            "Role.name.keyword": [
              "Developer",
              "Tester"
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "stof_64386038",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": 2.0,
        "_source": {
          "id": "2",
          "name": "Group1",
          "BusinessArea": [
            {
              "id": "14",
              "name": "Research"
            },
            {
              "id": "3",
              "name": "Accounting"
            }
          ],
          "Role": [
            {
              "id": "5032",
              "name": "Tester"
            },
            {
              "id": "5033",
              "name": "Developer"
            }
          ],
          "Designation": [
            {
              "id": "16",
              "name": "L1"
            },
            {
              "id": "20",
              "name": "L2"
            },
            {
              "id": "25",
              "name": "L2"
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "stof_64386038",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "3",
        "_score": 2.0,
        "_source": {
          "id": "1",
          "name": "Group1",
          "BusinessArea": [
            {
              "id": "14",
              "name": "Research"
            },
            {
              "id": "3",
              "name": "Engineering"
            }
          ],
          "Role": [
            {
              "id": "5032",
              "name": "Developer"
            },
            {
              "id": "5033",
              "name": "Developer"
            }
          ],
          "Designation": [
            {
              "id": "16",
              "name": "L1"
            },
            {
              "id": "20",
              "name": "L2"
            },
            {
              "id": "25",
              "name": "L2"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use bool query like this:

```
content_search = es.search(index="professor", body={
    "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
           {
          "terms": 
              {
            "BusinessArea.name.keyword": ["Research","Accounting"]
              }
           },
         {
           "terms": 
                  {
                    "Role.name.keyword": ["Developer","Tested"]
                  }
          }
      ]
    },
      "filter": [
        {
          "term": {
            "Location.keyword": "NY"
          }
        }
      ]
  }
})
```

Comment: Okay  @saeednasehi 

Comment: can you check the below question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64675696/how-to-get-the-individual-count-of-field-from-elasticsearch?noredirect=1#64675762